# Factorisation and factors

Tags: arithmetic

Factorise $3x^2 + 26x + 51$. Hence , find the two factors of $32651$

Workings 
$$3x^2 + 26x + 51= (x+3)(3x+17) $$

I don't understand how can I use the answer above to help me find factors of $32651$

Comment: Hint: $32651 = 3\times100^2 + 26\times100 + 51$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=100$,

Then $3x^2+26x+51=32651$

Hence $32651=(100+3)(3*100+17)$

It is easy to check both 317 and 103 are prime numbers.

Comment: I would credit the answer to @gammatester's hint.

Comment: A question for you: prove that 2438100000001 isn't prime! Further, if you know why, you can find it's factors! This is the inverse question, one far harder to answer if I give you a general number (say 667502283127 )

Comment: @abdefghijklmnopqrtxyz-stoo Clever question! $2438100000001=301*3^(4)*10^(8)+1=3^(5)*10^(10)+3^(4)*10^(8)+1$, $k^5 + k^4 +1 =(k^5+k^4+k^3+k^2+k+1)-k(k^2+k+1)=(k^3-k+1)(k^2+k+1)$, $let k=300, 2438100000001=26999701*90301$ Thanks for the cool problem

Comment: Im a new user, sorry if I messed up typing

Comment: congratulations, and that's fine if you occasionally slip up while typing. try the same for the other one (note: it is a crazy polynomial).